# How to create a class that calls upon methods from a different class?

Tags: java, methods

I recently started learning java this year in my school. We've gotten to a short chapter where we are creating a class that calls multiple methods from inside the class or outside the class. Our teacher gave us a demo showing us an class using methods from another class. This is the code from his example of this and called the class [Dog](http://pastebin.com/FLtxBqGa). He then creates another class called [DogDriver](http://pastebin.com/Ds7A373U). We then received a coding project. Here's what is must include. It's a program for a bank that must allow the owner to enter the bank account owner's name, money balance, and the amount the depositor would like withdrawn from their account. It will also need to allow the depositor to deposit and withdraw funds, and give error when the withdrawal exceeds the accounts balance. It needs 2 or more methods to call the program

I referenced back to the example he gave me and am having a hard time understanding the example so I can make the program. I think I get what it does, but when ever I try and code it myself, I seem to always get the “invalid method declaration; return type required”. I know I am doing something wrong but I would like to understand the way the program code I linked above works and how it can be used.

Any help is appreciated, Thank You

Here's my code. I was trying to understand the example program he created so I had taken it and edited it.

```
//January 27, 2015
public class Testing1{
 private double Balance;
 private String Name, Middle, Last;
 public AccountBalance(){ 
     Name = "Phillip";
     Middle = "J.";
     Last = "Fry";
     Blance = 300;
    }
 public accountBalance(String FirstName, String MiddleName, String LastName, double InitialBal){
    Name = FirstName;
    Middle = MiddleName;
    Last = LastName;
    Balance = InitialBal;
    }

 public String Name(){
    return Name;
    }
 public void SetBalance(double InitialBal){
     Balance = InitialBal;
    }
 public double GetBalance(){
     return Balance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Java docs are amazing! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: You did not show your own code and where you are getting errors

Comment: Post the code that you have tried so we could help you more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public AccountBalance(){...}
//and
public accountBalance(String FirstName, String MiddleName, String LastName, double InitialBal){...}
```

are (I assume you want them to be) constructors, therefore, they need to be the same name as the class name (here it is Testing1), and they are **CASE SENSITIVE** meaning `AccountBalance` does not equal `accountbalance`, eith change your constructors to match the class name :

```
public Testing(){...}
```

or refractor your class name to be `AccountBalance`

The error is because java thinks they are methods, which need return types.

Oh and, `Balance = 300` is spelt wrong in your first constructor

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you would like to call a method from a different class, it must be **public class**. Then you can call those methods from your main method.

```
Dog myDog = new Dog();
myDog.colour("White");
```

[Java Method Calling](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_method_calling.html)